# Mimic Low Bandwidth for UI Testing?

Tags: macos, testing, browser, bandwidth

How do you mimic low bandwidth for testing HTML rendering on slow computers?  I'm using Safari 4 on a Mac.

Comment: "lower the mimic low bandwidth"... you might check the text there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for traffic shaping, in MacOS X it's included in the kernel. Take a look at http://www.macgeekery.com/hacks/software/traffic_shaping_in_mac_os_x

Comment: There's an better solution using Apple's Network Link Conditioner. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @ErikAigner Great suggestion! At the time of writing the answer OSX Lion with it's Network Link Conditioner was not released, but you're absolutely correct that this would be the most convenient choice today.

Answer (score 10):

Found the [SpeedLimit](http://mschrag.github.com/) preference tool mentioned in another SO answer. Works for me and is very unobtrusive to use (no application, no command line, no Java).

Comment: This is a great little (app) it's actually a preference pane add in. Works great!

Answer (score 5):

If you have an Apple Developer account, look for the **"Hardware IO Tools for Xcode"** download. There is a **Network Link Conditioner** pref-pane included just for that with some good presets for

- 3G (Average/Good/Lossy)
- Edge (Average/Good/Lossy)
- WiFi (Average/Good/Lossy)
- Cable
- DSL

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699805/where-is-network-link-conditioner-prefpane-in-osx-mountain-lion-and-xcode-4-4)

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a local webserver (ie Apache) and use the traffic shaping capabilities thereof.

[An article on Apache throttling](http://mansurovs.com/tech/apache-bandwidth-throttling)

I guess most popular webservers support this.

*edit:Typos*

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using the [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/). It allows you to throttle your own bandwidth to simulate different connection speeds (and a whole mess of other stuff, too). Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program by Intrarts called "throttled", and the [command-line version](http://intrarts.com/throttledcli.html) seems to be free (price):

> throttled is a bandwidth shaping
>   application for Mac OS X and FreeBSD
>   which allows you to cap your upstream
>   bandwidth, prioritize ACK packets, and
>   keep your download speeds high even
>   when your server is sending out at
>   full speed.

...which seems to be a little tangential to your needs, but might be able to be configured to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a post on using waterroof](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/10/06/how-the-other-half-lives-bandwidth-throttling-on-the-mac-using-waterroofipfw/) to limit bandwidth a while ago.

It uses ipfw under the covers, but has a nice UI for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [Trickle for Mac](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Network-Admin/Trickle.shtml).

Alternatively, if you don't have to use Safari, you could use Firefox with the [Firefox Throttle plugin](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx).