# Where is Network link conditioner Prefpane in OSX Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, networking, osx-mountain-lion

I have recently updated to OSX Mountain Lion  Xcode 4.4. Now I can't find the bundled Network Link Conditioner anymore which was automatically installed on OSX Lion and the corresponding Xcode version.

Any ideas

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I figured it out. It looks like the Network Link Conditioner is now an optional package in Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4 which can be installed like so:

1. Open Xcode
2. Navigate to `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools`
3. Download the **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode** and then double click on the file `Network Link Conditioner.prefpane`, which will install the Preference pane again:

http://i.minus.com/jYNbvGpJabFmf.jpg

Comment: You can also download this and other packages (e.g. command line tools) separately from http://developer.apple.com

Comment: @PaulR Your are right, and essentially this is where **More Developer Tools** will take you.

Comment: FWIW I had problems installing the command line tools from within Xcode 4.4 (appeared to install OK but had silently failed) - but downloading them and doing it manually seems to have worked OK.

Comment: Ok so it looks like the prefPane still _should_ be in the command line tools but aren't because of an error in the command line tool installation.

Comment: Does the network link conditioner actually work on Mountain Lion though? I've reinstalled it from the location above but can't make it affect my connection.

Comment: It desn't work for me as well.

Comment: Removing the previous version and Installing it from the "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012" package from https://developer.apple.com/downloads fixed it for me, as pointed out by Sal.

Comment: As of May 2013, I can't find that "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012" download. Does anyone have a direct link?

Comment: @RobertAtkins Late July 2012: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/hardware_io_tools_for_xcode_4.4__late_july_2012/xcode44hwiotools6938115a.dmg • October 2013: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/hardware_io_tools_for_xcode__october_2013/hardware_io_tools_for_xcode__october_2013.dmg

Comment: For macOS 10.15 the download is called 'Additional Tools for Xcode' instead of 'Hardware IO Tools for Xcode'. Network Link Conditioner is part of this package.

Answer (score 9):

For the Network Link Conditioner that works in  Mountain Lion, you'll need to install it from the 'Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012' .dmg

Comment: ..and reboot. Although Apple doesn't mention this, it's required. And, after rebooting, you have to re-enable it (Apple automatically disables it on reboot)

Comment: And for XCode 9, it's stored in the "Additional Tools for XCode 9", they don't have a separate "Hardware Tools" any more.